# Python Threading with win32ui DDE module

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, dde

**EDIT**
Apparently this goes deeper than I thought; I just attempted to create the server inside the running thread, to no avail.

Running Python2.7 32 bit Windows. It would appear that the dde module (or the way I am using it?) does not play nicely with threads.

Here's stripped down code to demonstrate:

## This Works:

```
import win32ui
import dde
import threading

class Conversation(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, server, first, second, tag)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tag = tag #string
        self.first = first #string
        self.second = second #string
        self.server = server #dde server object

        self.conversation = dde.CreateConversation(server)

        #The focus of the problem. Here it works.
        self.conversation.ConnectTo(self.first, self.second)

    def run(self):
        print ""

def main():
    machine = "Irrelevant_MachineName"
    tag = "Irrelevant_Tagname"
    server = dde.CreateServer()
    server.Create("Irrelevant_ServerName")

    t = Conversation(server, "Irrelevant_Name", machine, tag)
    t.start()


main()
```

## This doesn't:

```
class Conversation(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, server, first, second, tag):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tag = tag #string
        self.first = first #string
        self.second = second #string
        self.server = server #dde server object

    def run(self):
        self.conversation = dde.CreateConversation(server)

        #Focus of problem.
        #Inside here it does not work.
        self.conversation.ConnectTo(self.name1, self.name2)

def main():
    machine = "Irrelevant_MachineName"
    tag = "Irrelevant_Tagname"
    server = dde.CreateServer()
    server.Create("Irrelevant_ServerName")

    t = Conversation(server, "Irrelevant_Name", machine, tag)
    t.start()


main()
```

## When it fails, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
    File "DDE.py", line 28 in run
     self.conversation.ConnectTo(self.first, self.second)
error: ConnectTo failed
```

Why would this be? This is going to be my first multithreaded program, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something stupid here.

But to me it seems perfectly reasonable that I should be able to call the dde.server.conversation object's ConnectTo method from within the threading module's "run()" method.

I'd looked into multiprocessing, but I don't think that's as applicable to my situation.

So, any ideas? I would greatly appreciate the help!!!

**edit**
*added in "threading.Thread.**init**(self)" to both failing and succeeding examples. Still no dice.*

**edit 2**

Also, I've heard tales of the tcl dde library, but know not where to find it. If anybody could provide me with a way to access it in python, I would be forever in your debt.

Comment: odd, seems like the stack trace should go deeper.  And is the library really so unhelpful as to merely state that it failed?

Comment: Evidently so. The only further information I have on the error is that it is of type "dde.error."

Comment: Is your first block of code not actually accomplishing your task?  You say that it "Doesn't fail epically."  Is it still failing and if so are you getting a different traceback?

Comment: Sorry @Benjooster: I should have clarified, the first block works totally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that with Windows DDE you're limited to using an instance of `ConnectTo` inside of the thread itself.  It does support multithreading, and while your `run` is still inside of your class it's possible that DDE sees that as outside your initial thread.  Don't know that that's actually an answer, but it seems to me that if you're first block of code is working it's entirely possible that this error is just an idiosyncrasy of Windows DDE and multithreading.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking... hoping it's not so, though, because this program really needs threading.

Comment: Are you not able to call multiple instances of the thread in the first block?  `Have you tried t1 = ... t1.start() and then t2 = ... t2.start()`?

Comment: I just tried it in the first block; it worked! But of course, the first block was working anyway. The second was the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, but you've got your threads now so you should be good to go right?

Comment: I mean having the threads wasn't the problem: it was the issue that whenever I call the "ConnectTo" method from within a thread, an error is raised and the program exits.

Comment: Are you trying to call back to the thread later?  In your first example the `ConnectTo` is working properly correct? So where else do you need to call the `ConnectTo`?

Comment: In the second example you see the problem; I cannot call ConnectTo from within the subclass of "Thread" once the "start()" method of the parent class "Thread" has been called.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, I think it might just be Windows DDE requiring it be called explicitly at the creation of the thread.  Past that I'm at a loss.  Sorry Marviel.

Comment: It's alright Benjooster, I appreciate your time. If I had more reputation, I'd upvote you!